# How can we mine Near Earth Objects?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, earth, asteroid, mining

After skimming this [Worldbuilding SE answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/129322/83467), I wonder if any companies or space agencies have plans in place to mine Near Earth Objects(NEOs) in the future.

Comment: Worldbuilding SE is a questions and answers site. It is not a discussion forum. Please edit the question to ask one clear question. You may want to re-take the [tour] and possibly visit the [help] again, in order to reinforce your acquaintance with the goals of this site.

Comment: Do you mean, "are people doing it (or planning to do it) now?" - well there's lots of chatter on the internet about that, but I'm not sure I see the worldbuilding issue to solve here.

Comment: I would suggest [space.se] as a better home for this question.

Comment: If possible, please move this question to space exploration...

Comment: The title asks 'how can we' and the body asks 'do we'...which is your question?

Comment: I think this question needs a lot of clarification. Short of that the answer is "yes", there are some people dreaming about mining NEOs and making money out of naiive investors/governments about the timescales involved, we could call that "in progress". As for reusing space debris that seems to be a different question entirely.

Comment: Big question - do we even agree what counts as mining? Economically viable in absolute terms requires something of tangible value - physical commodities - be returned to Earth profitably. In-situ resource use to reduce costs for not-for-profit taxpayer contracted missions can be profitable for the contractor but not the taxpayer. What to mine, how to mine, how or whether to refine on site or near Earth, how to move things around, how to land it on Earth, how to power it all? How to finance it? Question invites discussion not answers.

Comment: @KenFabian Thank you for input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short list to get you started, check out [Planetary Resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_Resources) and [Asteroid Mining Corporation](https://asteroidminingcorporation.co.uk/), and [Trans Astra](https://www.transastracorp.com/optical-mining).

I could swear I've heard Jeff Bezos talking about asteroid mining, but a quick search didn't return anything.

Comment: Planetary Resources is dead/MIA. As far as I can tell, what's left of the company/employees are now working on blockchain solutions for spacecraft and licensing their IP

Comment: Not a lot going on now. But if SpaceX succeeds with Starship wait 20 years and interests, activities and prospects might be looking up.